# How to reverse proxy a dynamic port with Apache?

Tags: apache, websocket, port, proxypass

I make a request to this URL:
**wss://domain/websockify?port=6801**
The port parameter can change dynamically. How could I make ProxyPass to redirect to a dynamic port extracted from the URL?

This is the configuration that works with a predefined port:

```
ProxyPass /websockify ws://localhost:6801/websockify/
ProxyPassReverse /websockify ws://localhost:6801/websockify/
```

If I use ProxyPassMatch the apache tells me there is an error:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/.*\?port=(.*)$ ws://localhost:$1/websockify/

#ProxyPass Unable to parse URL: ws://localhost:$1/websockify/
```

I use apache 2.4.10

Answer (score 1):

This needs to be done with mod_rewrite.

Match the port from the query string.
Redirect to the port that we matched in the condition with the [P] flag.
Use the same match in the ProxyPassRevese.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} port=(.*)
RewriteRule /websockify ws://localhost:%1/websockify/ [P]
ProxyPassReverse /websockify ws://localhost:%1/websockify/
```

Comment: You can't have %1 in ProxyPassReverse nor in ProxyPass